# How to join three tables without having a common column in Third table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sql-server-2016

I have three tables I.E. Table1, Table2, Table3. I can join table1 and table2 on the basis of prod_id column (which is common and relates table2 with the foreign key concept).

Now I want to join table3 with the result of table1 and table2, where all the columns are identical in table3. I tried row_number() but it doesn't give correct result.

How can I do this in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Can you provide some example data and table structure? Along with current and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a temp table or make a subquery, given that table3 relates to table1 and table2 by some kind of computable result:

```
SELECT
 t1.col1 + t2.col2 as t12_result,
 t1.col2,
 t2.col2,
INTO #temptable
FROM table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.prod_id = t2.prod_id;

SELECT t3.*, temp.*
FROM table3 t3
Left join #templtable temp on temp.t12_result = t3.col_id;
```

however if you want just to join on row-number (meaning there is no relation-key, the tables just happen to have same length and you keep them side by side), just create a row_number_id key on each and join. (here you need to realize that the row-number that SQL keeps internally is not the same as the row-number apparent to you).
You could create an artificial index-row on each table and join the tables on them, but this is gonna be tricky, as as said SQL internally does not care about the order of rows and reshuffles them, as long as you do not have a clustered hierarchical primary key set, which determines that order.